# How to pass a 'file' to cpp function that expects 'Buffer' in Python ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, mediainfo

I want to add 'Open_Buffer_Continue' function to the  MediaInfoDLL.py ctypes wrapper, the bindings are [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/mediainfo/code/HEAD/tree/MediaInfoLib/trunk/Source/MediaInfoDLL/) and
MediaInfoDLL.cs C# binding already implements this function so it's possible.

How do i pass the following:

```
file = open('./file.avi', 'rb')
```

to the mediainfo cpp [Open_Buffer_Continue](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Support/SDK/Doxygen/class_media_info_lib_1_1_media_info.html#af52ac48c91374312bc97821d3dc5a963) which expects:

```
(   const ZenLib::int8u *   Buffer,
    size_t                  Buffer_Size 
)
```

?

this is what i have so far:

```
MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init = MediaInfoDLL_Handler.MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init
MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init.argtype = [c_size_t, c_size_t]
MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init.restype = None

MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue = MediaInfoDLL_Handler.MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue
MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue.argtype = [c_size_t, c_size_t]  # NOT SURE HERE var 1
MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue.restype = c_size_t

MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize = MediaInfoDLL_Handler.MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize
MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize.argtype = [c_void_p]
MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize.restype = None
```

Comment: What's being continued?

Comment: process of feeding more data, if function returns 0 it has enough, otherwise it can be run again

Comment: @user1434058: `Open_Buffer_Continue` expects a **buffer**, previously associated with a file. e.g. check: http://mediainfococoa.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Lib/MediaInfo/Reader/Reader_File.cpp So I think there is more work to do like `Open_Buffer_Init`

Comment: posted what i have so far, Open_Buffer_Continue is the only problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about `mediainfo`, but it looks like `ZenLib::int8u*` is a pointer to bytes, so the best thing to use would be:

```
MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue.argtype = [c_char_p, c_size_t]
```

Then read your file into a string and pass it:

```
with open('./file.avi','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue(data,len(data))
```